# Changing the settings of columnbreak

Tags: columnbreak

I'd like to ask you if you know how to let the command `\columnbreak` make less horizontal space (-1.2cm) between two columns.

Answer (score 1):

`\columnbreak` is from the `multicol` package.  The default value for column separation is `1.5pc` which is `18pt`, roughly `0.63cm`.   You change this by using `\setlength`:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5pc}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

Standard \verb+\columnsep+
\begin{multicols}{2}
  Some text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.
  Some text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.

  \columnbreak
  More text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.
\end{multicols}

\bigskip

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5pc}
Narrower \verb+\columnsep+ put to \verb+0.5pc+
\begin{multicols}{2}
  Some text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.
  Some text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.

  \columnbreak
  More text.  And more.  And more.  A little more text.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note you have to change the value of `\columnsep` outside the `multicols` environment.

You may have visually more space than this if the your text is short and starts with a paragraph indent, cf. the first line of the above example.  You can kill that indent with `\noindent` before the relevant paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving solution and understandable description.